# iphone : Is it legal to send an email from my app via an external server (with a PHP script)

Tags: iphone, email, send

i wonder what is the best solution to send an email from my app.

I have two solutions :
1- using MFMailComposeViewController :
it works well. Easy to use. but use an huge amount of RAM : in activity monitor, when i use this, the RAM allocation grows from ~10 Mo to ~20Mo, and is never freed
2- Setup a PHP-Script that handles sending email.
it works very well too. And it uses very few RAM : around ~3 Mo with this solution.

So, my question is :
does this is allowed by apple ?

Does anyone is using this solution in his app ?

Comment: I'm not voting to close, because I'm not sure, but I *think* it's off-topic; and you should almost certainly seek guidance from Apple, or read through their documentation. I'm honestly not sure what the best resource would be for answering this question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure apple doesn't care how some email gets sent out when people use your app.

The more important issue is that when sending from the device, using `MFMailComposeViewController`, you get the following for free:

- users see a familiar interface
- users send their mail from their own account
- users have messages in their sent folder
- users can choose to archive a message

Using your own php script, you get:

- a lot of extra work to do, and stuff to maintain
- either A) always the same sender address (from your script), or B) an address that the user must type in (afaik there is no legal way to get an email address from iOS)
- in case B), trying to send on behalf of the user, you will run into spam filters quickly (think about SPF and such)

Looking at these things, the proposed solutions are really not comparable. So the real question is, what kind of email is sent out. Is it feedback sent to you, or is it mail sent on behalf of the user?

The memory concerns are new to me, I never experienced such problems. Do you handle memory management the proper way? If so, there is nothing to worry about. Don't focus too much on the "activity monitor" if you're not actually experiencing problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in a third alternative here. If you want to leverage a web service for emailing you could leverage an existing email service such as PostageApp (http://postageapp.com/). They have a a library you can use as part of your iOS / Mac app that interfaces with the API which allows you to send email from Objective-C. You can check out the plugin here: 
http://dev.postageapp.com/pages/plugins.html. The nice thing about leveraging a service like this is you don't have to worry about the internals of sending email and lets you focus on your application.

(Disclosure: I work for PostageApp and built the plugin)